# React Router v6 Nested Routes doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to render subroute with nested routes  .

Expected results -> /bilgi/detay

I've tried like this but it doesn't return any page ..

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="bilgi"  element={<Information />} >
           <Route path='detay'  element={<Contact/>}/>
        </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Please reread [ask] and especially [mcve]. Thank you for sharing your code, but what "doesn't work"? Are the results incorrect, do you get an error, does your computer explode...? Please [edit] the question to clarify what the problem with this code is and what the desired outcome is.

Comment: your question does not contain enough information

Comment: I meant it returns empty page

Comment: in the information component ,you should use <Outlet/>

Comment: Now ıt renders both components on same page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested `Route` components need an `Outlet` component to be rendered into.

Apply either of the following:

1. Have `Information` component render the `Outlet` for the nested routes to be rendered into. This renders the entirety of `Information` along with the content of the nested routes.

   ```
   import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...

   const Information = () => {
     ...

     return (
       <>
         ... Information JSX ...
         <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
       </>
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
     <Route path="bilgi" element={<Information />} >
       <Route path="detay" element={<Contact />} />
     </Route>
   </Routes>
   ```
2. Convert `path="bilgi"` into a layout route that renders the `Outlet` alone and move `Information` into its own nested index route to be rendered on the matching path of the layout route. Routes render an `Outlet` by default if no `element` prop is provided. This renders each routed component individually.

   ```
   <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
     <Route path="bilgi">
       <Route index element={<Information />} />
       <Route path="detay" element={<Contact />} />
     </Route>
   </Routes>
   ```

Read more about [index routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-routes) and [layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes).

You could OFC, not nest the routes at all and render a flat list of routes with absolute paths.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/bilgi" element={<Information />} />
  <Route path="/bilgi/detay" element={<Contact />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/bilgi" exact element={<Information />} />
    <Route path='/bilgi/detay' exact element={<Contact/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot render the child route content with **children** anymore.
The New version of **react-router-dom** uses the **Slot/Outlet** concept like what vuejs has.
We need to indicate that where the parent-provided slot content should be rendered.

Then you need to add  in the Information component.

Check the sample here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/4d915e3305df5b01f51abdeb1c01bf442453522e/examples/scroll-restoration/src/app.tsx